# Внутреннее закругление Border плюс тень

Tags: javascript, html, css

```css
#main {
  margin: 40px;
  height: 200px;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  background-color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div id="main"></div>
```

[image: Внутреннее закругление углов]

Помогите решить проблему. Не получается одновременно сделать внутреннее закругление углов и нормальную тень.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно не идентично, но думаю суть ясна. Делаем имитацию вогнутой части с помощью `box-shadow`:

```css
body {
  background: url("http://www.yorkpress.co.uk/resources/images/6599017.jpg?display=1&htype=0&type=responsive-gallery")20% 10%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.wrapper {
  margin: 1rem;
}

.item {
  position: relative;
  background-color: white;
  width: 500px;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.item:first-child {
  box-shadow: 0 -1rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.item:last-child {
  box-shadow: 0 1rem 1rem rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}

.item:first-child::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: -0.7rem;
  border-top-right-radius: 60%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 60%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  box-shadow: 15px 0px 0 4px white;
}

.item:first-child::after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  right: -0.7rem;
  border-top-left-radius: 60%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 60%;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  box-shadow: -15px 0px 0 4px white;
}

.item:last-child::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 1rem;
  bottom: 90%;
  background-color: white;
  width: 93%;
  height: 50px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3rem black;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```